# Ubuntu version for Gazebo

Tags: xubuntu, ros

I would like to know compatible ubuntu version for latest Gazebo 11 and if possible  ROS version also. Now Im using Ubuntu 18.04 for gazebo 9.0 and Ros Indigo
Thanks in advance

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 and above it's still version 9. You can search with packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: [Debian Science Maintainers](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=debian-science-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org) volunteers package Gazebo for Debian and Ubuntu. They could use [some help](https://packages.qa.debian.org/g/gazebo.html) with it.